# SQLite errors table created and queried correctly

Tags: android, database, json, android-sqlite

I'm having this problem and working on it from 3 hours right now but everything seeming fine isn't getting things working on correctly, I'm creating the table and feeding the database table correctly but the insert doesn't seem to work and I receive the following error:

```
08-14 15:13:47.590: E/SQLiteDatabase(8606): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Code": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO login(uid,created_at,Device Code,email,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
08-14 15:13:47.590: E/SQLiteDatabase(8606):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-14 15:13:47.590: E/SQLiteDatabase(8606):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1012)
08-14 15:13:47.590: E/SQLiteDatabase(8606):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
08-14 15:13:47.590: E/SQLiteDatabase(8606):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-14 15:13:47.590: E/SQLiteDatabase(8606):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-14 15:13:47.590: E/SQLiteDatabase(8606):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
08-14 15:13:47.590: E/SQLiteDatabase(8606):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
08-14 15:13:47.590: E/SQLiteDatabase(8606):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
08-14 15:13:47.590: E/SQLiteDatabase(8606):     at library.DatabaseHandler.addUser(DatabaseHandler.java:73)
08-14 15:13:47.590: E/SQLiteDatabase(8606):     at com.database_demo.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:71)
```

The method that is generating this error is as follows:

```
* Storing user details in database
     * @param string 
     * @param  
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at, String DeviceCode) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At
        values.put(KEY_Device_Code, DeviceCode);

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

The condition that is calling the ABOVE error generating method with the String parameter valures is as follows:

```
if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                            if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                                // user successfully logged in
                                // Store user details in SQLite Database
                                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                                JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                                // Clear all previous data in database
                                userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                                db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT),  json_user.getString(KEY_Device_Code));                     

                                // Launch Dashboard Screen
                                Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                                // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                                dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(dashboard);

                                // Close Login Screen
                                finish();
                            }else{
                                // Error in login
                                loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                            }
                        }
```

after following TARUN's advice i now get the following error:

```
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277): org.json.JSONException: No value for "Device Code"
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at com.database_demo.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:71)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
08-14 16:11:37.925: W/System.err(10277):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quote your `KEY_Device_Code` column name since it contains space.

`Device Code` should be `"Device Code"`

Escape your device code as `String KEY_Device_Code= "\"Device Code\"";`

Comment: so finally it should be like >>  private static String KEY_Device_Code = "\"Device Code\"";

Comment: Exactly.. You need to escape your column name.

Comment: i changed  private static String KEY_Device_Code = "Device Code"; TO  private static String KEY_Device_Code = "\"Device Code\"";

Comment: 1> What is the exact column name in your database for Device Code

Comment: 2> What is the json object name for Device code.. Are they both same?

Comment: in the database within the table the exact column name is Device Code

Comment: Yes, in that case you have to escape the database column name. What about json one?

Comment: in the JSON its also Device Code

Comment: Got it man its done, I KNEW I'M PUTTING THIS SPACE THING WHILE CODING THIS WILL GET ME IN GREAT TROUBLE AND HERE IT IS IT GOT ME 3 HOURS WASTED!

Comment: yea.. you should never use space .. If you can you should replace it so as not to get into trouble again.. glad you get it working ..